# Perl: If always returning true

Tags: perl, if-statement

I am just getting back into Perl programming so I appologize if this is an easy/stupid question.

My If statement is returning true (never going to the else) and I'm not really sure why. For example this code never prints "getshere":

```
@showName = ("Matt","Matt","Matt","Gym","Gym");

$counter=0;
foreach (@showName)
{
    if ($showName[$counter]==$showName[$counter+1])
    {
        print "$showName[$counter] equ $showName[$counter+1]\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "getshere";
    }
    $counter++;
}
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: comparing strings needs the string comparison operator `eq` like tthis `if ($showName[$counter]  eq $showName[$counter+1])`

Comment: Always `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 8):

`==` is numeric comparison, and strings like `'Matt'` and `'Gym'` all have the numeric value `0`, so they're all `==` to each other. For string comparison, use `eq` instead:

```
    if ($showName[$counter] eq $showName[$counter+1])
```

(I recommend enabling warnings, by the way, by adding `use warnings;` near the start of your script. Had you done that, you would have received a helpful message warning you that you were applying a numeric equality-test to non-numeric values.)

Answer (score 3):

The `==` operator converts strings to numbers and does numeric comparison.  To compare strings, use `eq`.  To test if strings are greater or less than eachother, use `cmp`.

```
if ($showName[$counter] eq $showName[$counter+1])
```